# Automated json responses

Tags: json, http, response

I am looking for a configurable http server which can look at the http request and return an automated json response. Is there any open source tool available?

Example :

### Request

```
GET http://127.0.0.1/path/keyword
```

### Response :

```
{ status : 200 }  <-- This response i want to hard code based on the keyword.
```

-- Cobe